# How to limit the number of search query in "Bing Search - Cognitive Services"?

Tags: bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I need to limit the number of search queries in my subscription for Bing Search API v5.0. I don't want to exceed the number of query allowed in the subscription.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not a way to limit or set caps for your subscription allowance.  You can monitor your usage through the Azure portal.  This request is on our backlog of requested features.  Thank you.